# Запрос на несколько условий

Tags: sql

Совсем недавно на этом же сайте мне показали как сделать запрос на выбор данных из 4-х таблиц, взяв это за пример я сделал другой запрос:

```
        SELECT L.*,
        (SELECT group_concat(distinct client.client_full_name) 
        FROM client 
        JOIN cases ON (client.client_id=cases.client_id) 
        JOIN lawyer ON (lawyer.lawyer_id=cases.lawyer_id) 
        GROUP BY lawyer.lawyer_full_name) clientname,
        (SELECT count(cases.lawyer_id) 
        FROM cases 
        JOIN lawyer ON (lawyer.lawyer_id=cases.lawyer_id) 
        WHERE cases.case_archive=1
        GROUP BY lawyer.lawyer_id) archive
        FROM lawyer L
```

Выдает мне ошибку, я не понимаю почему и как ее исправить...

Задача запроса получить строки на каждого адвоката (таблица lawyer) все (*) его данные + список его клиентов сейчас (достать из таблицы cases) и сума его архивных дел (тоже из cases, только тут cases.case_archive=1).

Предоставляю так же онлайн модель базы для удобной проверки запросов: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9130c/

И последнее: прошу описать каждый шаг запроса, я очень путаюсь в запросах и вот засоряю форум почти одинаковыми темами...

Comment: в `group_concat` separator не нужен?

Comment: Выглядит жутковато :) запрос очень странно заканчивается на `FROM lawyer L, client CL` без условий по которым эти таблицы клеятся `WHERE`. В итоге перемножаются все записи адвокатов на всех клиентов. сильно сомневаюсь что так задумано

Comment: И запятая после `) archive` явно не в кассу

Comment: И что такое "сумма архивных дел". сейчас вы делаете sum по `id` адвокатов в делах. сомневаюсь, что сумма ID кому то интересна

Comment: @Mike Да, я ту запятую на пробнике заметил после публикации поста и удалил. Условия склеивания вы имеете ввиду USING или GROUP BY?

Comment: @Mike Сумма ID адвокатов это количество строк этого адвоката в делах. Это, по сути, тоже самое что количество дел адвоката. Кстати там нужно добавить `cases.case_archive=0` ибо архивные нам не нужны

Comment: @Levelleor `WHERE`. Вы начинайте всегда с простых запросов и смотрите, что они выдают. в данном случае `select * FROM lawyer L, client CL` Т.е. просто из уловия выборки опщена пара подзапросов. Вот они вам ворох записей выдадут

Comment: @Levelleor количество - `count`. А `sum` для 2 дел адвоката с ID 3 выдаст результат 6

Comment: @Levelleor И самое главное. У вас подзапросы в списке выборки основного запроса никак с ним не связаны. Там по хорошему не нужны даже group by. Но необходима связь с id адвоката из основного запроса, т.е. из `L`

Comment: @Mike Так мне нужно получить совершенно все данные таблицы адвокатов, тогда `select L.* FROM lawyer L` верен. Да, я перепутал `sum` с `count` :)

Comment: @Levelleor Но у вас там еще зачем то `,client CL` во `from`

Comment: @Mike Я обновил запрос в посте с учетом всех правок. Но ошибка `Subquery returns more than 1 row` . Но где там больше одного значения? В плане я запрашиваю много имен за раз, как сделать что бы они не ругались?

Comment: @Levelleor Правильно ругается. подзапрос в списке выборки, т.е. в самом select должен вернуть только 1 значение, относящиеся только к текущей записи основного запроса. вот для этого в нем и нужно обязательно условие связывающее его с `L` из основного запроса

Comment: @Mike Вы имеете ввиду `lawyer.lawyer_id` заменить на `L.lawyer_id` ? Или как это сделать?

Comment: @Levelleor Дал предварительный ответ. проверяйте пока, то ли выбирает, что требовалось. чуть позже напишу как добавлять подзапрос в список выборки. И постарайтесь форматировать запросы, когда они у вас по левому краю, разобрать что к чему относится невозможно. Если вы его так же записываете, когда создаете, то начинаете путаться в частях и это сильно тормозит работу. Вставка пары пробелов перед FROM в итоге экономит кучу времени :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще подзапросы в списке выборки - это крайний случай. Да, он удобен. Но обычно он утяжеляет запрос. Его надо использовать тогда, когда обычных средств не хаватает. Например, если основной запрос, произведя склейку нескольких таблиц создает такое кол-во записей, что по ним уже нельзя получить сумму какого то поля, т.к. одно и то же значение этого поля встречается несколько раз.

Примерный план составления такого запроса:

1. Определяем участвующие таблицы. Во главе у нас `lawyer` т.к. именно из нее надо получить все записи, вне зависимости от наличия дел и клиентов. Для получения количества дел надо добавить таблицу `cases` и для получения клиентов таблицу `client`, причем она клеится через дела.
2. Составляем базовый запрос:

   ```
   SELECT *
     FROM lawyer L
     LEFT JOIN cases  S ON (L.lawyer_id=S.lawyer_id)
     LEFT JOIN client C ON (S.client_id=C.client_id)
   ```

   Мы используем *только* `LEFT JOIN` - таким образом адвокаты будут точно все.  Наличие записей в остальных таблицах не требуется.

   Проверяем запрос, смотрим все ли записи, которые нам нужны для последующего суммирования у нас выдались. Да, все. Причем есть имена всех клиентов и есть все дела по адвокату. Хотя нас интересует только кол-во архивных дел, а у нас в запросе все дела (если всех дел не будет, мы получим не всех клиентов). Значит нам надо как-то хитрее посчитать кол-во дел. Применим `IF`.
3. Добавляем группировку и групповые функции

   ```
   SELECT L.*,
          group_concat(distinct C.client_full_name) clients,
          sum(IF(S.case_archive=1,1,0)) case_arx_sum,
          count(S.case_id) case_all_sum
     FROM lawyer L
     LEFT JOIN cases  S ON (L.lawyer_id=S.lawyer_id) 
     LEFT JOIN client C ON (S.client_id=C.client_id)
    GROUP BY L.lawyer_id
   ```

   По поводу групповой функции с IF. обычный `count(S.case_id)` считает все NOT NULL значения и таким образом посчитает кол-во дел и не затронет записи, в которых только адвокат без единого дела. А мы хотим получить все архивные дела, делаем `SUM` по условию, которое должно выдать для суммирования 1 для архивных дел и 0 во всех остальных случаях, включая отсутствие дел

Предположим, нам надо было бы в этом запросе показать заодно суммарное наказание клиентов данного адвоката. Если мы приклеим таблицу `punishment` в этот же запрос то некоторые дела буду попадаться несколько раз, т.к. записи просто размножатся, в случаях когда есть несколько наказаний у клиента. Если есть 2 дела и 2 наказания - то мы получим 4 записи, со всеми вариантами дело/наказание. В такой ситуации посчитать кол-во чего либо будет крайне сложно. Поэтому тут нам поможет как раз подзапрос в списке выборки.

Подзапрос должен возвращать *одно* значение для каждого адвоката. Пишем его сначала как отдельный запрос, который получит нужное значение для ID одного конкретного адвоката. нам нужен только ID адвоката, поэтому таблицу самих адвокатов использовать не обязательно, до нужной нам ID мы можем добраться через таблицу дел (`cases`). Получаем такой запрос для адвоката ID=1:

```
SELECT sum(P.punishment_value)
  FROM punishment P, cases C1
 WHERE C1.client_id=P.client_id and C1.lawyer_id=1
```

осталось только вставить его в основной запрос, использовав в качестве id адвоката соответствующий id из основного запроса (`C1.lawyer_id=L.lawyer_id`):

```
SELECT L.*,
           group_concat(distinct C.client_full_name) clients,
           sum(IF(S.case_archive=1,1,0)) case_arx_sum,
           count(S.case_id) case_all_sum,
           (SELECT sum(P.punishment_value)
              FROM punishment P, cases C1
             WHERE C1.client_id=P.client_id and C1.lawyer_id=L.lawyer_id) punish_sum
      FROM lawyer L
      LEFT JOIN cases  S ON (L.lawyer_id=S.lawyer_id) 
      LEFT JOIN client C ON (S.client_id=C.client_id)
     GROUP BY L.lawyer_id
```

Comment: Идеально. Впрочем как всегда, но у меня есть вопросы. На счет `IF`: в моей таблице дел `cases` значения NOT NULL если строка вообще будет. Я имею ввиду что если есть адвокат в ЭТОЙ таблице то будет и дело ибо эта таблица их связывает. Вопрос чисто из интереса, выходит в моем случае можно указывать `count` без `IF`?

Comment: Стоп, я понял, что ничего не понял. Чем отличаются эти 2 строки: `sum(IF(S.case_archive=1,1,0)) case_arx_sum`,`count(S.case_id) case_all_sum` ?

Comment: @Levelleor Я в запросе специально привел `case_all_sum` - это как раз количество всех дел адвоката и считается оно как раз count() причем по полю case_id, потому как count не считает кол-во NULL значений и не посчитает адвокатов без дел. А `case_archive` я и не вывожу. я его использую внутри `IF`. По факту `IF` выдает `1` которую `sum` добавляет к сумме. И `IF` это делает только если совпало его условие т.е. для `case_archive=1`. NULL это не 0 и не 1 так что условие IF на него никогда не среагирует

Comment: @Levelleor У меня в запросе в `where` или `on` признак архивного дела не проверяется и запрос работает со всеми записями и с архивными и с рабочими. Иначе бы он не выдал гарантированно _всех_ клиентов для адвоката

Comment: А почему запрос не сработает верно, указав в `ON` дополнительное условие `case_archive=1`? Не выведет весь список дел? Я о нем изначально и не думал.

Comment: @Levelleor По `case_archive=1` в `ON` он выберет только архивные дела, при этом таблица `client` будет приклеена уже к этому набору строк и таким образом мы на выходе получим только клиентов адвоката только по архивным делам. А я так понял нас интересовали вообще все клиенты. Если нас интересуют только клиенты по архивным делам, то да - такое условие в ON и кол-во дел просто count()

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32919/discussion-between-levelleor-and-mike).